# Why is `realloc()` failing on certain mysterious inputs?

Tags: c, memory, realloc

I've already spent hours trying to figure out why my program fails on this input, but it's still kind of a mystery to me. First, here's the relevant details to reproduce this error.

Using the files listed below in the same directory, compile with `gcc -O0 -g main.c ArrayList.c` (note: `gcc --version` outputs `7.3.0`). Afterwards, run `./a.out $((10**9))`. You should get the following error:

```
a.out: malloc.c:2868: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (GLRO (dl_pagesize) - 1)) == 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've already tried debugging through this and the problem doesn't seem to be my code i.e. the error seems to be thrown in `realloc`'s code, but I honestly don't know. If I use `./a.out $((10**10))`, the program doesn't fail, which is mysterious to me. The issue seems to be this line:

```
arraylist->data = realloc(arraylist->data, sizeof(uint64_t) * (arraylist->capacity));
```

I've read through the man pages for clues to whether I'm calling realloc incorrectly, but nothing jumped out to me. All the program is trying to do is sieve out the non-primes less than sqrt(n) using a modified sieve of eratosthenes. Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

---

main.c:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ArrayList.h"

// Segment addressing.
#define BYTE_IDX(i) i >> 4
#define BIT_IDX(i) (i >> 1) % 8

// Bit manipulation.
#define IS_PRIME(i) ~(S[BYTE_IDX(i)] >> BIT_IDX(i)) & 1U
#define SET_BIT(i) S[BYTE_IDX(i)] |= (1U << BIT_IDX(i))

uint64_t primepi(uint64_t n)
{
    uint64_t sqrtn = (uint64_t)sqrt((double)n);
    uint8_t *S = calloc((sqrtn + 1) / 16, sizeof(uint8_t));

    ArrayList arraylist;
    arraylist_init(&arraylist);

    for (uint64_t i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
        if (IS_PRIME(i))
        {
            arraylist_append(&arraylist, i);
            for (uint64_t j = i * i; j * j <= n; j += 2 * i)
                SET_BIT(j);

        }

    free(S);
    arraylist_free(&arraylist);
    return (uint64_t)0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint64_t n = primepi(atoll(argv[1]));
    printf("n = %lu\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

ArrayList.h:

```
/**
 * ArrayList.h
 *
 * Summary:
 *  Provides a specification of the ArrayList data structure.
 */

#define ARRAYLIST_INITIAL_CAPACITY 128

typedef struct {
    uint64_t size;
    uint64_t capacity;
    uint64_t *data;
} ArrayList;

void arraylist_init(ArrayList *arraylist);

void arraylist_append(ArrayList *arraylist, uint64_t value);

uint64_t arraylist_get(ArrayList *arraylist, uint64_t index);

void arraylist_double_capacity_if_full(ArrayList *arraylist);

void arraylist_free(ArrayList *arraylist);
```

ArrayList.c:

```
/**
 * ArrayList.c
 *
 * Summary:
 *  Provides an implementation of the ArrayList data structure.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "ArrayList.h"

void arraylist_init(ArrayList *arraylist)
{
    // Initialize size and capacity.
    arraylist->size = (uint64_t)0;
    arraylist->capacity = ARRAYLIST_INITIAL_CAPACITY;

    // Allocate memory of the arraylist->data.
    arraylist->data = calloc(arraylist->capacity, sizeof(uint64_t));
}

void arraylist_append(ArrayList *arraylist, uint64_t value)
{
    // Double ArrayList if it is full.
    arraylist_double_capacity_if_full(arraylist);

    // Append the value and increment the size.
    arraylist->data[arraylist->size++] = value;
}

uint64_t arraylist_get(ArrayList *arraylist, uint64_t index)
{
    if (index >= arraylist->size || index < (uint64_t)0)
    {
        printf("Index %lu out of bounds for ArrayList of size %lu\n", index, arraylist->size);
        exit(1);
    }
    return arraylist->data[index];
}

void arraylist_double_capacity_if_full(ArrayList *arraylist)
{
    if (arraylist->size >= arraylist->capacity)
    {
        arraylist->capacity *= (uint64_t)2;
        arraylist->data = realloc(arraylist->data, sizeof(uint64_t) * (arraylist->capacity));
    }
}

void arraylist_free(ArrayList *arraylist)
{
    free(arraylist->data);
}
```

---

Edit:

Output from running `valgrind --tool=memcheck ./a.out $((10**9))`:

```
==31666== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31666== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31666== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31666== Command: ./a.out 1000000000
==31666== 
==31666== Invalid read of size 1
==31666==    at 0x1089E7: primepi (main.c:29)
==31666==    by 0x108AA7: main (main.c:40)
==31666==  Address 0x55cb7f8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,976 alloc'd
==31666==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31666==    by 0x108952: primepi (main.c:19)
==31666==    by 0x108AA7: main (main.c:40)
==31666== 
==31666== Invalid write of size 1
==31666==    at 0x108A17: primepi (main.c:29)
==31666==    by 0x108AA7: main (main.c:40)
==31666==  Address 0x55cb7f8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,976 alloc'd
==31666==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31666==    by 0x108952: primepi (main.c:19)
==31666==    by 0x108AA7: main (main.c:40)
==31666== 
==31666== Invalid read of size 1
==31666==    at 0x108982: primepi (main.c:25)
==31666==    by 0x108AA7: main (main.c:40)
==31666==  Address 0x55cb7f8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,976 alloc'd
==31666==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31666==    by 0x108952: primepi (main.c:19)
==31666==    by 0x108AA7: main (main.c:40)
==31666== 
n = 0
==31666== 
==31666== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31666==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31666==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 70,584 bytes allocated
==31666== 
==31666== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31666==
==31666== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31666== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Does running your program through valgrind give you any errors?

Comment: Crank up your warning levels, I get a bunch of interesting warnings, one of which is `warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'uint64_t' to 'size_t', possible loss of data`

Comment: I get `n = 0`. Are you sure you've posted an [MCVE]?

Comment: I get this assertion at onlinedbg.com

Comment: Even `uint64_t n = primepi(/*atoll(argv[1])*/1000);` yields zero on my system using VS2018.

Comment: @Shawn, I've posted the output from running valgrind using memcheck at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @jwdonahue, can you please list the gcc flags you used get that warning? It should return `n = 0`, and this doesn't matter because it's irrelevant to the error produced. The code listed should allow you to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in you SET_BIT macro:

```
#define SET_BIT(i) S[BYTE_IDX(i)] |= (1U << BIT_IDX(i))
```

or maybe in your BYTE_IDX macro:

```
#define BYTE_IDX(i) i >> 4
```

or maybe in this loop:

```
for (uint64_t j = i * i; j * j <= n; j += 2 * i)
            SET_BIT(j);
```

it accesses out of bound the `S` array.

When:

- argv[1] = "1000000000"
- n = 1000000000
- sqrtn = 31622
- DYNAMIC_ARRAY_SIZE(S) = (sqrtn + 1) / 16 * sizoef(uint8_t) = 1976

the maximum index for S is 1975. Setting SET_BIT macro to:

```
#define SET_BIT(i)  do{ \
    size_t _a = BYTE_IDX(i); \
    if (_a > 1975)  \
        fprintf(stderr, "Setting byte %ld\n", _a); \
    S[_a] |= (1U << BIT_IDX(i)); \
}while(0)
```

we can see in the output:

```
Setting byte 1976
```

You are writing out of bound for the S array which overwrites *alloc data - it throws an assertion.

Live code available at [onlinedbg](https://onlinegdb.com/SkiRdzd57).

To your code:

- Using any argument outside macro is bad. If you use `S` inside a macro pass it as an argument, maybe with a size argument, that way you can write an assertion. You just discovered why `IS_PRIME` and `SET_BIT` macros are bad. I like your idea of indexing bitfields very *very* much - just write a proper library for that, just like for arraylist.
- `size_t` is the type for storing sizes. Use size_t for `ArrayList.size` and `ArrayList.capacity`. Use `uint64_t arraylist_get(ArrayList *arraylist, size_t index);`. Would be also nice, as you work with big numbers, to check for multiplication overflow, the expressions `arraylist->capacity *= (uint64_t)2;` and `sizeof(uint64_t) * (arraylist->capacity)` may overflow.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed a problem with how I allocate memory for `S`. My current method allocates this many bytes: `Floor[(Floor[Sqrt[n]] + 1) / 16]`, but the _correct_ formula should've been: `Ceiling[Floor[(Floor[Sqrt[10^9]] + 1) / 2)] / 8]`. This was causing my code to not have enough enough bits to store the numbers below Floor[Sqrt[n]].